# Error while creating Gradient Descent Model for a new dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter

```
import pandas as pd 

file = pd.read_excel('slr06.xlsx')
# Data 
x = pd.DataFrame(file, columns=['X'])
y = pd.DataFrame(file, columns=['Y'])
# Parameters 
w = 0.0
b = 0.0
# HyperParameters 
learning_rate = 0.01

# Creating Gradient Descent 

def descend(x, y, w, b, learning_rate):
    dl_dw = 0.0
    dl_db = 0.0
    n = x.shape[0]
    # loss = (y-yhat)**2
    for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
        dl_dw = -2*xi*(yi-(w*xi+b))
        dl_db = -2*(yi-(w*xi+b))
    # Make an Update
    w = w - learning_rate*(1/n)*dl_dw
    b = b - learning_rate*(1/n)*dl_db
    
    return w, b
# Iteratively make updates 
for epoch in range(500):
    w, b = descend(x, y, w, b, learning_rate)
    yhat = w * x + b
    loss = np.divide(np.sum((y - yhat)**2, axis=0), x.shape[0])
    print(f"{epoch} loss is {loss} parameters w: {w} | b:{b}")
```

I am new to ML and I was practicing with a dataset and I got error

[This is the picture of a dataset -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoVwl.png)

[This is the picture of error -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGDdt.png)

I was creating a gradient descent model that I have practiced before with a different dataset. This I tried with random data to practice and better understand Gradient Descent

Comment: Not related to the error, but your update logic is wrong. You iterate over all samples and overwrite the `dl_` variables without using them in the loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do **not** post screenshots of code or error messages - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ambiguous error comes from a wrong datatype, i.e. because of a multiplication like `[1,2] * 1.0 or "hello" * 3`

Your error comes from a wrong iteration approach similar to this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
>>> for x in df:
...     print(x)
A
B
```

---

**Your `xi, yi` variables are strings**, when multiplied with a float leading to the error.

---

There are multiple ways you could change your code. However the most efficient would be to do:

```
# Do not duplicate memory, and use a Series instead of a data frame
x = file.X
y = file.Y
```

Now the for loop part throws no error anymore.
Furthermore you can use vectorization without the need of a for loop, if you do full batch gradient descent.

---

PS: Something to remember: iterating over a dataframe is often a bad idea as there are more efficient methods.